# "Microwaved" or "Micro waved"

Tags: word-choice

As an adjective describing something that has been cooked in a microwave, would you say "microwaved" or "micro waved"? The dictionary says microwaved, but my autocorrect corrects to micro waved.

Comment: You would say microwaved. The dictionary is generally viewed as more authoratitive than "autocorrect".

Comment: Alternatively use 'micro-waved'. Most spell checkers give up when you throw a hyphenated term at them.  Actually, in this case, don't. These days microwaved is always one word in my experience.

Comment: A "micro wave" is a slight twitch of the finger.

Comment: Ah, but how do you feel about "microwaveable"?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Ask your dishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microwave is a range of radio frequencies of electromagnetic propagation emitted

- in microwave ovens to cook food
- by radar to either cook rabbits prancing in the vicinity or to reach far distant objects to detect their presence
- in cellphone communication, which has the possibility of cooking your brain cells by placing the phone next to your ear, or your other cells by placing the phone in your pockets.
- in computer circuitries that have for the past 10 years reached microwave frequencies, such that placing a laptop on your lap might do your descendants a disservice.

Hence, microwaving would mean subjecting the target to the cooking action of microwaves.

Micro waving is a picture I get of nano-robots or engineered bacteria waving at us, saying "Hello there gods our wonderful creators."

Answer (score 2):

According to the OED, use "microwaved" to describe something

> Irradiated with microwave radiation; spec. cooked or heated in a microwave oven.

"micro waved" has no reference under either "micro" or "waved".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [oxforddictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com) gives *microwave* as being:

> [to] cook (food) in a microwave oven: he microwaved some steak out of
>   the freezer

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/microwave

I would generally trust a dictionary over auto correct